# ubuntu как правильно вставить test –e

Tags: linux, ubuntu

как правильно вставить test –e в скрипт чтоб 
если в папке /mnt/srv/basket/1c кончится место он мне на почту пришлет сообщение что файлы не записались

скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $fname

mkdir -p /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname —mode=777 
for f in /mnt/backup/1c/*.bak
do
ff=${f##*/}
zip -r /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname/${ff%.*}.zip $f » /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname/$fname.log
done
echo "email" | mail -s "BackUp Log File $fname" name.mail@mail.ru < /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname/$fname.log ;
```

Comment: вы ничего не путаете? `test -e файл` возвращает `true`, если `файл` существует. и `false` в противном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. у вас ошибка:

   ```
   zip -r /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname/${ff%.*}.zip $f » /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname/$fname.log
   ```

   перенаправление (без обрезания файла) осуществляется оператором `>>`, а не типографскими кавычками `»`.
2. как я понял, вам надо обработать ошибку при выполнении именно этой команды: при её возникновении отправить письмо и завершить работу скрипта.
   это можно сделать, например, так:

   ```
   zip ... >> ... || {
     res=$?
     mail -s "backup error $res" name.mail@mail.ru" < \
     /mnt/srv/basket/1c/$fname/$fname.log
     exit $res
   }
   ```
3. ещё одна ошибка. здесь `echo "email" |` — лишнее:

   ```
   echo "email" | mail -s "BackUp Log File $fname" name.mail@mail.ru < /mnt/srv/baske
   ```

   достаточно так:

   ```
   mail -s "BackUp Log File $fname" name.mail@mail.ru < /mnt/srv/baske
   ```

Comment: очень красивый ответ спасибо

Comment: who is it "$?" я так понял альтернатива "test -e"

Comment: и еще одна проблема теперь почему то все скрипты выполняемые после мне приходят на почту ) к примеру если после архивации файла мне приходило письмо примерно с таким текстом  add file «/mnt/backup/1c/AN30_backup_2016_01_09_230001_2636141.bak» 56 %
то теперь он мне присылает лог только с текстом (удален «/mnt/backup/1c/AN30_backup_2016_01_09_230001_2636141.bak»)

Comment: переменная `$?` содержит код возврата последней выполненной программы.

Comment: по поводу «проблемы» (суть которой я не уловил), наверно, лучше задать новый вопрос.